# Rotating button when downloading data from server

Tags: iphone, ios

I want to rotate a UIButton when connection start and want to stop rotating when connection stop.

So my question is how to start or stop rotation on UIButton.

I use the following code for rotation.

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:5.0];

// (180 * M_PI) / 180 == M_PI, so just use M_PI
btn.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI);

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove animations from a view by calling `removeAllAnimations`

```
[btn.layer removeAllAnimations];
```

Make sure you import QuartzCore before accessing layer properties, otherwise you may get a warning.

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

To make the view animate continuously use the `+ (void)setAnimationRepeatCount:(float)repeatCount` method on `UIView` and set it to some arbitrary high number.

```
[UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:5000];
```

Comment: Thanks working but how to rotate button until downloading get complete because it's rotating only once